# actionmailer crashing after changing smtp settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All my mailing code was working fine until i decided it was time to change adress the email was being sent from to the production email (i had been using my personal gmail account up until now for testing).

When i made the switch i started getting a TypeError with the following stack trace

```
TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:575:in `initialize'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:575:in `new'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:575:in `ssl_socket'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:580:in `tlsconnect'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:560:in `do_start'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:519:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:144:in `deliver!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2034:in `do_delivery'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/message.rb:229:in `block in deliver'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.11/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:415:in `block in deliver_mail'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.11/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:413:in `deliver_mail'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/message.rb:229:in `deliver'
from (irb):1
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
```

The only thing that changed between this working perfectly and getting the above stack trace is the change in smtp settings. Here are my before and after smtp settings (sensitive information excluded of course)

Before (using a gmail account):

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "www.domain.com",
  :user_name            => "username",
  :password             => "password",
  :authentication       => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  
}
```

After (not a gmail account):

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.domain.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "www.domain.com",
  :user_name            => "username",
  :password             => "password",
  :authentication       => :login,
  :openssl_verify_mode  => :none,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  
}
```

I have tried changing the authentication type and a couple of other attributes but nothing is working.

Comment: I have similar problem with ruby 1.9.1. I set stmp_settings attribute on the body of my mailer method (multi smtp configuration)